# Unparseable date exception while converting UTC time in java

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I am sorry if its a very stupid mistake that i am doing but i cant seem to see it. I am getting an Unparsable date exception while trying to parse 2012-08-28T21:52:57.020Z by using SimpleDateFormat with "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" as the format string. Can some one please point me to the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think SimpleDataFormat parses "Z" in the parsed String as a time zone. :( It only tread `Z` in the format as the place to find the time zone.

Try the format `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"` or try JodaTime which has better handling of time zones.

Comment: It does and represents the the timezone: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: It works right now, and I am in too much of a hurry to go deep. Maybe later. Thanx a lot :)

Comment: @Vikdor I have tried to clarify the confusion. There is a `Z` in the format which is ok, and a `Z` in the string parsed which is not. The work around is to assume there is `Z` in the string parsed.

Answer (score 2):

The 'Z' in the end corresponds to the time zone. You should replace that 'Z' in your input with time zone ID like IST/EST etc.,

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
String date = "2012-08-28T21:52:57.020IST";
System.out.println(df.parse(date));

output: Tue Aug 28 21:52:57 IST 2012
```

Comment: In this case `Z` is the time zone. Same as `GMT` or `GMT+0` or `+0000` of which SimpleDateFormat only parses `GMT`.